# React setState occurs after second click

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I have two Components which are functional. The first one is Parent and the second one is Child and on Parent I have some states and a function which retrieve some data from server and base on it, setData is called then this state is passed to Child to be shown.

The problem is when I first click on a button to trigger that function, state does not change but on second click state is changed and data is shown on Child component.

My Parent is like:

```
const Parent= () => {

const [data, setData] = useState();

const handleShowDetails = (id) => {
       const mainData = data
       MyServices.GetData(
      command,
      (res) => {
       mainData = res.name;
        }
    );
    setData(mainData);
}
}

  return (
  <Child
    data={data}
    handleShowDetails={handleShowDetails}
  />
);
```

And my Child is like:

```
const Child= ({data, handleShowDetails}) => {
return(
  <div>
     <button onClick={() => handleShowDetails()}/>
     {typeof data!== "undefined" ? (
          <div className="col-1">
                {data}
           </div>
       ) : ("")
  </div>
)
}
```

What can I do to fix this issue?

Note: I implemented MyServices for handling API calls by Axios.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting state even before your `GetData` call is completed, which must be asynchronous. So setData is called with the old value of `data`.

Try this:

```
const handleShowDetails = (id) => {
       const mainData = data
       MyServices.GetData(
      command,
      (res) => {
       mainData = res.name;
       setData(mainData);
        }
    );
}
```

Or use await pattern:

```
const handleShowDetails = async (id) => {
       const mainData = data
       const ans = await MyServices.GetData(command);
       setData(ans.name);
);
}
```

Note: No need to use mainData i guess.

Comment: In "MyServices" I used async and await. Unfortunately this wasn't useful for me. And thanks for your advice about mainData.